# Ссылки меняют цвет после размещения на хостинге

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Помогите понять причину сего поведения ссылок: При верстке на локальной машине, ссылки были белыми, как и прописано в CSS. После размещения на хостинге становятся розовыми или как еще назвать этот цвет.

Вопрос - Почему? Как исправить хочу догадатся сам, но не могу ответить на вопрос - почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стили перекрываются из файла `reset.css` на строке 66.
Сброс вообще-то должен быть в самом начале, поэтому поменяйте очередь загрузки.

Comment: В точку! О ресете я не подумал. +1 в карму.

Comment: @AlexSMiheev, тут +10 :) Не за что.